# Jar file crashing but netbeans project works

Tags: java, file, path, jar, nullpointerexception

I have exported my project as a jar file earlier today and it is crashing. From what I can tell it is due to file locations within my project.

The following is the console output when the jar is run:

01/05/2011 18:34:15 [0x0-0x9ca9ca].com.apple.JarLauncher[45211] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

01/05/2011 18:34:15 [0x0-0x9ca9ca].com.apple.JarLauncher[45211]     at java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.(Arrays.java:3357)

01/05/2011 18:34:15 [0x0-0x9ca9ca].com.apple.JarLauncher[45211]     at java.util.Arrays.asList(Arrays.java:3343)

01/05/2011 18:34:15 [0x0-0x9ca9ca].com.apple.JarLauncher[45211]     at examples.FileRetriever.getFiles(FileRetriever.java:25)

01/05/2011 18:34:15 [0x0-0x9ca9ca].com.apple.JarLauncher[45211]     at examples.GUI.initComponents(GUI.java:64)

01/05/2011 18:34:15 [0x0-0x9ca9ca].com.apple.JarLauncher[45211]     at examples.GUI.(GUI.java:37)

01/05/2011 18:34:15 [0x0-0x9ca9ca].com.apple.JarLauncher[45211]     at examples.MasterClass.main(MasterClass.java:13)

FileRetriever class is as follows:

```
public static Vector<String> getFiles(String d) {
    File dir = new File(d);
    children = dir.list();

    FilenameFilter filter = new FilenameFilter() {
        @Override
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            return !name.startsWith(".");
        }
    };
    children = dir.list(filter);

    fileNames = new Vector<String>(Arrays.asList(children));
    return fileNames;
}
```

And the line from the GUI class that calls this is: 
`files = FileRetriever.getFiles("src/examples/Media");`

I'm positive that it's the directory given as the argument in getFiles. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: do you planning that the files in `src/examples/Media` are found in the jar file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very probably you're not launching it in the same working directory as when you run it from netbeans.

Comment: I am launching it from the "dist" folder of my project at the moment. The problem is, how should I change this so that it would run on another computer?

Comment: Construct the absolute path of your file, or pass it as an argument.